# Use of "list" in data.table's j argument

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning data.table properties from [a blog post](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#columns-of-lists). I am trying to understand the part under "summary table (short and narrow)", starting by coercing data.frame(mtcars) to data.table:

```
> data <- as.data.table(mtcars)

> data <- data[,.(gear,cyl)]
> head(data)
    gear cyl
 1:    4   6
 2:    4   6
 3:    4   4
 4:    3   6
 5:    3   8
 6:    3   6
```

Up to this point everything is fine.

Now I have tried this `data[, gearsL := list(list(unique(gear))), by=cyl]`

```
> head(data)
   gear cyl gearsL
1:    4   6  4,3,5
2:    4   6  4,3,5
3:    4   4  4,3,5
4:    3   6  4,3,5
5:    3   8    3,5
6:    3   6  4,3,5
```

I am able to understand **unique(gear)** but unable to understand  what **list(list(unique(gear))** is doing.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am learning data.table properties from http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/. I am trying to understand part under summary table (short and narrow)

Comment: The outer `list()` is used to list a bunch of columns, like `list(col1, col2)` as is the same as the `.(col1,col2)` you used above. `.()` is just an alias. The inner `list()` just makes a `list`, the same as everywhere else in R. You are making a `list`-class column vector: i.e., one where each row contains a `list`. I think it makes the most sense to go through introductory material for the package before "advanced" tutorials. The official ones are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: I have learnt basics from datacamp website. Now I am trying to learn more about data.table

Comment: @DeepakYadav, thanks for reading my blog post.  Hope you're finding it useful.  +1 to Frank's answer.  I naively didn't realize the outer `list( ` was equivalent to `.(`  I made an update to [the post](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/) linking to this question.  Thanks Frank and Deepak.

Comment: What's the difference between  .(col1, col2)  and (col1, col2) without the dot?

Comment: Just randomly came across this post again and realized that I also saw it ~2 years ago and updated my blog post accordingly.  Also updated with some feedback from Matt Dowle.  
http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#columns-of-lists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A data.table -- like any data.frame -- is a list of pointers to column vectors.

When creating new columns, we write `j` of `DT[i,j,by]` so that it evaluates to a list of columns:

```
DT[, (newcol_names) := list(newcol_A, newcol_B)]
```

That's what the outermost `list()` in the OP's example does, for a single `list` column.

> ```
> data[,gearsL := list(list(unique(gear))), by=cyl]
> ```

This can and should be written using the alias `.()`, for clarity:

```
data[, gearsL := .(list(unique(gear))), by=cyl]
```

That's all you need to know, but I've put some elaboration below.

---

**Details.** When creating a new column, we can often skip `list()`/`.()`:

```
DT = data.table(id=1:3)
DT[, E := c(4,5,6)]
DT[, R := 3]
# this works as if we had typed
# R := c(3,3,3)
```

Note that `E` enumerates each value, while `R` recycles a single value over all rows. Next example:

```
DT[, Elist := list(hist(rpois(1,1)), hist(rpois(2,2)), hist(rpois(3,3)))]
```

As we did for `E`, we're enumerating the values of `Elist` here. This still uses the shortcut; `list()` is here only because the column is itself a `list`, as confirmed by

```
sapply(DT, class)
#        id         E         R     Elist 
# "integer" "numeric" "numeric"    "list"
```

The convenient shortcut of skipping `list()`/`.()` fails in one special case: when we are creating a `list` column that that recycles its value:

```
DT[, Rlist := list(c("a","b"))]
# based on the pattern for column R, this should work as if we typed 
# Rlist := list(c("a","b"), c("a","b"), c("a","b"))
```

It doesn't work because the parser sees this as `C2 := .( c("a", "b") )` and thinks we simply neglected to make a full enumeration with one value for each row, like `Elist` does. To get the desired result, skip the shortcut and wrap the vector in `list()`/`.()`:

```
DT[, Rlist := .(list(c("a","b")))]

#    id E R       Elist Rlist
# 1:  1 4 3 <histogram>   a,b
# 2:  2 5 3 <histogram>   a,b
# 3:  3 6 3 <histogram>   a,b
```

This is the case in the OP's example, where the outer `list()`/`.()` is necessary.

Comment: I'm doubting that this issue deserves such detail, but, eh, it's already written.