# Correlationmatrix from data table

Tags: r, data.table, correlation

If I have the following data table:

```
set.seed(1)
TDT <- data.table(Group = c(rep("A",40),rep("B",60)),
                      Id = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      x1 = sample(100,100),
                      x2 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x3 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x4 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x5 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2))
```

How can I calculate the correlations between x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5 by Time?

This:

```
TDT[,x:= list(cor(TDT[,5:9])), by = Time]
```

does not work.

How can it be done in `datatable`?

Comment: Your data don't have multiple observations for each combination of Id and Time, as would be necessary for calculating correlations. Try `TDT[Id==1 & Time == "2010-01-02"]`, or any other combination of Id and Time. Each is just one row.

Comment: @Rose Hartman Ah sorry my bad, I meant just by Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close in your attempt! All you missed was an extra `list()`.

This works:

```
TDT[,x:= list(list(cor(TDT[,5:9]))), by = Time]
```

And `TDT$x` returns:

```
[[1]]
            x1          x2          x3         x4          x5
x1  1.00000000  0.72185099  0.07368766 -0.7031890 -0.36895449
x2  0.72185099  1.00000000  0.68058833 -0.7393130  0.05066973
x3  0.07368766  0.68058833  1.00000000 -0.5021462  0.10645894
x4 -0.70318896 -0.73931299 -0.50214616  1.0000000  0.11671020
x5 -0.36895449  0.05066973  0.10645894  0.1167102  1.00000000

[[2]]
           x1         x2          x3          x4         x5
x1  1.0000000 -0.1011948 -0.85191422 -0.15571603  0.4855237
x2 -0.1011948  1.0000000  0.56691559 -0.44002621 -0.6699172
x3 -0.8519142  0.5669156  1.00000000  0.02189754 -0.6168013
x4 -0.1557160 -0.4400262  0.02189754  1.00000000  0.2236542
x5  0.4855237 -0.6699172 -0.61680132  0.22365419  1.0000000

[...]
```

The extra `list()` is needed because of how `data.table` parses the second element of the `DT[1,2]` syntax. This has been discussed in depth elsewhere in stackoverflow, with a [most excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115273/1601756) that I invite you to read.

As a side note, it seems preferable to replace the outermost call to `list()` with `.()` to clarify the intent. I also like to single out explicitly the columns with a reference to `.SD` and `.SDcols`. With the same outcome, you could rewrite your code as:

```
TDT[, x := .(list(cor(.SD))), by = Time, .SDcols = 5:9]
```

Comment: Hey Jealie, I am working with really big datasets and I was wondering if your solution could be adapted to the circumstance where I would want the correlation of only one column/variable with all the other columns/variables. Is there some way I can make data.table handle/skip non-numerical columns as well (it is okay if they simply provide NA's)?

Comment: @Tom that's a bit more involved, it would be better ask a new question for this on SO. :)

Comment: I did! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182271/getting-the-correlation-with-significance-of-one-variable-with-the-rest-of-the-d

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [corrr](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr) package useful for this. In combination with [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) commands, you can easily get the correlation matrix for different groups.

```
library(data.table) # not necessary unless you want the data in this format for other reasons
library(dplyr)
library(corrr)
```

Get correlation matrix for each Id:

```
> TDT %>% 
+   group_by(Id) %>%
+   do({
+      correlate(select(., x1:x5))
+     }) 
Source: local data frame [25 x 7]
Groups: Id [5]

      Id rowname          x1           x2          x3           x4          x5
   <dbl>   <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1      1      x1          NA -0.246252411 -0.24589380 -0.181120555  0.14781414
2      1      x2 -0.24625241           NA  0.32098291 -0.175603686 -0.08863810
3      1      x3 -0.24589380  0.320982911          NA  0.161336670  0.07934436
4      1      x4 -0.18112056 -0.175603686  0.16133667           NA -0.19662700
5      1      x5  0.14781414 -0.088638098  0.07934436 -0.196627000          NA
6      2      x1          NA  0.075760735  0.41276725  0.425032505  0.37178993
7      2      x2  0.07576074           NA  0.07747543 -0.004202306 -0.08086958
8      2      x3  0.41276725  0.077475426          NA  0.248151847  0.07619264
9      2      x4  0.42503251 -0.004202306  0.24815185           NA  0.37647798
10     2      x5  0.37178993 -0.080869584  0.07619264  0.376477979          NA
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Get correlation matrix for each Time:

```
> TDT %>% 
+   group_by(Time) %>%
+   do({
+     correlate(select(., x1:x5))
+   })
Source: local data frame [100 x 7]
Groups: Time [20]

         Time rowname          x1          x2          x3          x4          x5
       <date>   <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2010-01-02      x1          NA -0.66584960 -0.58788152  0.92540707  0.37316217
2  2010-01-02      x2 -0.66584960          NA -0.06102424 -0.69292534  0.19440850
3  2010-01-02      x3 -0.58788152 -0.06102424          NA -0.54623949 -0.78714932
4  2010-01-02      x4  0.92540707 -0.69292534 -0.54623949          NA  0.53697784
5  2010-01-02      x5  0.37316217  0.19440850 -0.78714932  0.53697784          NA
6  2010-02-02      x1          NA -0.10444724 -0.62424401  0.30109335  0.04834057
7  2010-02-02      x2 -0.10444724          NA -0.12010431  0.08966978 -0.68762698
8  2010-02-02      x3 -0.62424401 -0.12010431          NA -0.92782037  0.52099983
9  2010-02-02      x4  0.30109335  0.08966978 -0.92782037          NA -0.58214861
10 2010-02-02      x5  0.04834057 -0.68762698  0.52099983 -0.58214861          NA
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: very good, ty. Do you also know how to do this in `data table`?

Comment: No I don't, sorry :)

Comment: Very nice solution. Do you know how to get p.values ?

Answer (score 1):

`split` by `Time` and then run `cor` for each sub-group

```
lapply(split(TDT, TDT$Time), function(a) cor(a[,5:9]))

#OR

lapply(split(TDT[,5:9], TDT$Time), cor)
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works, However, it does not use the `datatable`syntax either.

Comment: @user3032689, `TDT[,5:9][,cor(.SD), by = TDT$Time]`?

Comment: oh that works, but it seems weird to me that you can split by `Time`, which is not contained in `TDT[,5:9]` anymore.

Comment: Also in both of your answers, the format is different from the one of Rose's answer, which seems better for the purpose. Especially the `datatable`version is kind of confusing in this regard. Any way to fix that? Applying `list`to `cor(.SD)`does not work.