# Is there a trick to save a list to a cell in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I came across a problem where I was unable save a list to a cell in a data.table in what I would think would be a fast / 'native' data.table way.

Below is a reproducible example to show the problem.

- I was expecting Attempt #1 to provide the same results as Attempt #3, but it gave an error saying, "*... Supplied 13 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 1...*".
- Attempt #2 gave the error, "*'from' must be of length 1*".
- Attempt #3 works, but feels like a hack and I'm assuming it slower than a legit data.table method.

Does anyone have a solution and or an explanation of why Attempt #1 was flawed?

Many thanks!

```
# Set up data ----
library(data.table)
myDT <- data.table(MyID = 1:8, MyPeriod = 11:18, agency = rep(c('ONE', 'TWO'), 2), 
                   start_v2 = as.Date(c('2018-12-12', '2018-11-11', '2018-10-10', '2018-09-09', '2018-08-08', '2018-07-07', '2018-06-06', '2018-05-05')), 
                   end_v2 = as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-04-04', '2020-06-06', '2020-08-08', '2020-10-10', '2020-11-11', '2020-12-01', '2020-12-31')))

# Attempt #1 ... why doesn't this work?----
myDT[, month_year_alt := list(format(seq(start_v2, end_v2, by = "month"), "%y-%m")), by = .(MyID, MyPeriod, agency)]

# Attempt #2 ... I wondered if perhaps I couldn't save a list to a cell when I had a `by` argument, so I dropped it but it still doesn't work----
myDT[, month_year_alt := list(format(seq(start_v2, end_v2, by = "month"), "%y-%m")),]

# Attempt #3 ... this method works but (a) I am guess it is slower than a native data.table method and (b) does not allow for grouping by my variables----
for(ii in 1:nrow(myDT)){
  myDT[ii, month_year := list(format(seq(start_v2, end_v2, by = "month"), "%y-%m")), ]
}
print(myDT[])
```

Comment: What if you wrapped it in another list - `myDT[, month_year_alt := list(list(format...` ?

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail! This works perfectly. Could you briefly explain why?

Comment: In data.table, the outermost list() is interpreted as wrapping a list of columns, so list(list(x)) is needed for a list column. Verbose explainer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113013/use-of-list-in-data-tables-j-argument/33115273#33115273

Comment: @Frank ... that link was helpful. It makes perfect sense now. I appreciate the insight.

Comment: In `data.table` syntax you will often see that `.(list(..` is used instead of `list(list(..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@thelatemail solved this problem for me (thank you!). The following works perfectly:

```
myDT[, month_year_alt := list(list(format(seq(start_v2, end_v2, by = "month"), "%y-%m"))), by = .(MyID, MyPeriod, agency)]
```